# Custom soft keyboard for android run time changing

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have made a soft keyboard app as seen here: [custom soft keyboard](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)

Now I need an option to change background of that keyboard from my MainActivity. How do I do that?
Here is the code:

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
{
private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;

private boolean caps = false;

@Override
public View onCreateInputView()
{
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}

private void playClick(int keyCode){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(keyCode){
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)
{
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the MainActivity with the button which should change the background:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Change keyboard background
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to add a image on background layout or change as a theme?

For only changing the background color you need to add the Background Color in your Layout file and for theme you need to create the theme 1st than implement on java code. Like for theme as a sample;

// For Sample Default Theme

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:id="@+id/mainview">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBack">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_item"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="4px"
        android:background="@drawable/images"
        android:keyTextSize="18sp"
        android:keyBackground="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And for Newly Created Default Theme implementation in java will be below:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
    View view = null;
    if (themes != null && themes.equals("default")) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.default_theme, null);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openOptionsMenu(v);
                }
            });
            kv = (KeyboardView) view.findViewById(keyboard);
            //kv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
            qwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
            kv.setKeyboard(qwertyKeyboard);
            kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            kv.setOnTouchListener(new HapticListen(7));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                kv.setBackground(drawable);
            }
            return view;
        }else {
            return  null;
        }
      }
```

Hopefully, i will help you to understand.